# develop android app for gingerbread honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, android-2.2-froyo

I'm a new android developer. I'm developing an app for android Gingerbread (2.3.3) and I would like my app to be used in a Tablet with HoneyComb 3.0.

My questions are:

1. What is the best approach, develop the app first to Gingerbread and adapt it to Honeycomb?. (or that kind of think is insane?)
2. Do you have any suggestions about the design of the app for a better adaptation to both OS versions?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't worthy of being an answer, but mind your layouts, and make multiple layouts for the differing screen sizes.  Especially keep in mind font sizes.  Nothing is more frustrating than micro-text in an app on my tablet.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm a beginner in Android and also in Stackoverflow. I thought it was a very good question. For me it's essential because I was developing my application completly in the opposite way. I don't know how can I remove my question if it's possible. Sorry again for the inconceniences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fragments. There is a static library that should allow you to write for Honeycomb and maintain compatibility all the way till Donut. See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)
Also read android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html . It covers some aspects of designing a single application to run on both phones and tablets. It looks like if the applications follow the guidelines set here, then Ice Cream Sandwich compatibility should be trivial at worst.